# Fetching Recently added rows from table

Tags: oracle-10g, select, order-by

I have the following table structure ,

**name      || description || timestamp**
  varchar       varchar        date

time stamp column consists of time the row is added

Now i need to fetch the recently entered 5 records .. How should i query the table .

Note:
i am using oracle 10g

**Update** :

```
select * from table orderby timestamp desc where rownum<6
```

Is that right approach ??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `where` clause is applied first, and the `order by` is applied to the results, you need to use a subselect as follows:

```
select * from (
  select *
  from table
  order by timestamp desc
)
where rownum <= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
       `Select * From my_table
       Where Row_number<6
       Order by Timestamp Desc:
```

`
I think it will work

Comment: Thanks will try and update . i didnt downvote your answer

Comment: This won't work: the `where` clause is applied first and then the `order by`.